# Dual problem for standard simplex

Tags: optimization, simplex

How the dual problem will look like for the following negative-entropy minimization problem?

$\min \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i \log x_i,$

S.t. $x_i \geq 0, i=1,...,n, \sum_{i=1}^n x_i=1$

Thank you.